# systemd macchanger start job hanging

Tags: systemd, startup, mac-address

I am running Arch Linux and I have set up `systemd` to change my MAC address on startup with `macchanger`

```
# /etc/systemd/system/macspoof@.service  
[Unit]
Description=macchanger on %I
Wants=network-pre.target
Before=network-pre.target
BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/macchanger -r %I
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I enabled it with `systemctl status macspoof@wlp4s0.service`
and everything was fine.

So a few weeks later it the following happened:
Every time I start up my machine, it would hang on starting that service.
It would say something like

```
...
A start job is running on macspoof@...
...
waiting 1s/...
```

It didn't happen at first.
Now when this happens, I wildly press the spacebar, enter and etc keys and eventually it goes away by doing that.
If I did nothing, it would probably stay...
Also there is no timeout on this, so it would run indefinitely.
This now happens every time I start up my machine (a thinkpad x260), and I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Have you gotten any insights on this?

Comment: @Aiyion.Prime unfortunately I have not.